# Jetbrains Rider with Mono and C# 7.0 Features

Tags: c#, mono, rider

I started using Mono 5.2 with Jetbrains Rider and i got the following error in some peaces of my code:

[image]

So, looking at my Compiler settings i just have MSBUILD 14.0, i if i'm not wrong i need MSBUILD 15.0 to C# 7.0 works, right ?

How can i fix it ?

**Edit 1**
I setted the language to C# 7.0 but i can't use C# 7.0 features, see:

This don't work:

```
   return (int?)idCompanhia;
```

I got the following error:

[image]

But this works fine:

```
return (int)idCompanhia;
```

**Edit 2**
This is my method using this **int?**

```
 public static int? ObterIdCompanhia(string companhia)
        {
            int.TryParse(companhia, out var idCompanhia);
            return idCompanhia == 0 ? null : (int?)idCompanhia;
        }
```

Comment: Have you [checked this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/ReSharper_by_Language__CSharp.html)? Do you have the C#7 compiler instaled?

Comment: I edited my post with some informations, i already setted the C#7 compiler.

Comment: The error in `return (int?)idCompanhia;` seems to be a runtime error, which means that the code compiled successfully. I cannot say what the cause is, without seeing the relevant declarations and the context. Please post code as text, not as image, if possible.

Comment: I edited the post with method that uses this "int?"

Comment: Have you tried ‘out int idCompanhia’? And then don’t cast it as an integer here ‘: (int?) idCompanhia’